# Does pyopencl require discrete graphics?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, python, intel-graphics, opencl

When I try to install the package `pyopencl`, it pulls in Nvidia stuff (`nvidia-current`, I think).   This appears to install without problems, but then messes up my OpenGL-related things.   I thought a big part of the appeal of OpenCL is that it's .. open, not tied to Nvidia.

Is there a (hopefully easy) way to install and use PyOpenCL without pulling in Nvidia stuff, or (more importantly / precisely) without breaking my OpenGL setup?   I realize that I'll see little in the way of performance advantages of OpenCL this way, but I want it for development, anyway.

Running Ubuntu 12.04, Intel 965GM integrated graphics.

Comment: This might be worth bringing up with the Ubuntu maintainers. I've just checked myself to confirm this. Trusty only wants to pull the Nvidia ICD and not the drivers so it looks like someone has noticed an issue, it just hasn't been fixed in Precise.

Answer (score 0):

Neither OpenCL nor PyOpenCL require any GPU at all. Try this [howto](http://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo) for setup instructions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the link (and for all your work). // I may use that link, but - this being AskUbuntu - I was hoping for an Ubuntu-specific answer. IDK why the default package pulls in the Nvidia stuff. (It would be nice if the maint would change that.) I was hoping for something like "You can install the package and uninstall the nvidia part and it works fine" or "Download and manually unpack it, then run the __ script" or "Here's an alternate ppa". Sure, maybe the 'real' way is easy enough, but this is Ubuntu - home of the *really* lazy (and/or new-to-linux).